# Bash check if any blank space in the file

Tags: bash, shell

the below function is not working is the file has some blank spaces or tabs.

```
get_value()
{
 file="/u01/app/file.lst"
 if [ -f $file ];
 then
   echo "file.lst file exists, Checking values"
   if [ -s $file ];
   then
       while IFS= read -r value
      do
         variable=`echo $value`
      done < "$file"
        echo "Variable values is : $variable"
   else
      echo "file.lst file is empty,Default value for variable is 10"
      variable=10
      echo $variable
    fi
 else
   echo "file.lst file doesnot exists, ,Default value for variable is 10"
   variable=10
   echo $variable
 fi
}
```

pls help how to check file contents with blank spaces also

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Please explain in detail. Are you getting error messages? Is the output incorrect? Give an example input, your expected output, and the wrong output produced by your program. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help people understand the problem and provide better answers.

Comment: if file.lst has some blank spaces it is considering it has some values

ls -ltr file.lst shows 2 instead of 0. in this case it is considering some values in the file rather than empty

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Thanks, but where can i keep file.lst to check in shellcheck.net

Comment: `if grep -q '[[:blank:]]' file; then echo "contains blanks"; else echo "no blanks"; fi` should do the trick. Your code is unintelligible.

Comment: the requirement is to check whether file exists or not. if it exists check the value in the file and assign to variable. If file doesn't exists or if it is empty the default 10 will be assigned to variable. sometimes the file has blank space also in this case it is not considering as empty file. i am new to shell so still learning

Comment: Relevant to `if it exists check the value in the file and assign to variable`: What _value_?

Comment: some integer value example 15

Comment: if file.lst doesnot contains any values then be default variable value assigned to 10

script is not checking if any white blank spaces in the file.lst

Comment: What if file contains more than one line? What if the file content consists of `15xyz` or `xyz42` or `qwe`?

Comment: file size showing 1. it is empty but it has some white spaces

-rw-rw----. 1 odbadmin oinstall 1 Feb 15 14:51 file.lst

when i do cat it is empty cat file.lst shows nothing but cat file.lst | wc -l shows 1 which is white space

Comment: yeah sorry but i dont know how to check those all

Comment: So, only *one line* content in the file?

Comment: yes only one line with integer value

Comment: Your script is orders of magnitude more complex than necessary and contains several beginner errors; probably try https://shellcheck.net/ to get many of them diagnosed. It's not clear what exactly you want to accomplish, but you seem to be looking simply for `grep ' ' file`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one line in a file then a `while` loop is not needed. Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

get_value(){
  local variable file
  file="/u01/app/file.lst"

  if [[ ! ( -e $file && -f $file ) ]]; then
    variable=10
    printf '%s does not exists, Default value for variable is %d\n' "${file##*/}" "$variable"
    printf 'Variable value is: %d\n' "$variable"
    return
  fi

  IFS= read -r variable < "$file"

  if [[ -z $variable ]]; then
    variable=10
    printf '%s is empty, Default value for variable is %d\n' "${file##*/}" "$variable"
    printf 'Variable value is: %d\n' "$variable"
    return
  fi

  printf 'Variable value is: %s\n' "$variable"
}

get_value
```

---

- The default value for the variable can be done with a Shell Parameter Expansion with `"${variable:-10}"`
- The `if` clause/statement can be replace with a command grouping via the curly braces `{ }` something like: `[[ ... ]] && { command-goes-and-other-things-here; }`